# How do I project an image onto a mesh and have it reflect in the unwrapped UV?

Tags: uv-image-editor

Probably best to give an example. I have an unwrapped UV mesh of a mug, which is in the form of islands which I do not want to change. I would like to project an image onto it which is visible as intended only from the camera. So when I examine the mesh in the viewport, parts of the image will be distorted (like a physical projector putting out an image onto a complex surface.

I would like this image (in it's distorted form) to appear on the unwrapped UVs of the mug. Unfortunately, I can't share the file, but I'm basically trying to create a decal which is only visible as intended from one camera. And print this decal. Hope that makes sense. All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're asking, you could give your object a material with your picture loaded in an *Image Texture* node, choose your view, unwrap with the *Project from View* mode:

[image]

Then, in the *Object Data panel > UV Maps*, create a second UV map for the same material with seams along the top and on one vertical edge and unwrap with the basic *Unwrap* mode. Give your material a second *Image Texture* with a black image called *bake* for example, don't plug this *Image Texture* but plug an *Input > UV Map* node into it. In this new *UV Map* node select the second UV map you've just created. Keep the second *Image Texture* selected. Go into the *Render* panel, under *Bake* choose *Bake Type > Diffuse*, disable *Influence > Direct and Indirect*, and bake:

[image]

Now you can save your *bake* image and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure that I've understood your question, but it looks like you are looking for UV project modifier:

[image]